# VBA What's wrong with this MsgBox Syntax

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

When I try to compile I'm given this error:

> Compile error:
>
> Syntax error

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub ErrorHandler()
'   The code is cleaned up by using ErrorHandler as a function because it has to be written out fewer times, and makes changing ErrorHandler easier

MsgBox("Error detected" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Error " & Err.Number, vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error " & Err.Number)

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need the brackets.

Comment: That's so simple of a fix! Thanks.

Comment: I've voted to close this question since this pretty much just counts as a typo. Glad you got your answer anyway!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

unless a subroutine is returning a value,i.e. being assigned to a variable  there is no need to use paranthesis

```
MsgBox "Error detected" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Error " & Err.Number, vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error " & Err.Number
```

if msgbox needs to give back an answer then, the following is the correct syntax

```
response = MsgBox ("Error detected" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Error " & Err.Number & "Do you want to retry", vbYesNo, "Error Handler: Error " & Err.Number)
```

Comment: Thanks! What did you change?

Comment: Should probably specify what you are doing there to solve the issue with that code.  Not entirely obvious to everyone.

Comment: @ThomasShera He removed the brackets () since they aren't needed in the format that you call that function.

Comment: Also an interesting point is that sometimes the brackets are needed even when calling a function that doesn't return a value. I ran into a situation that took me a long time to solve due because it didn't have the brackets.   So another way you can do it is simply by putting `Call MsgBox("Test")`  So far that seems to be the universal works in every situation method.  Though I suppose it just comes down to personal preference.